# How to track and isolate filehandler leaks

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

I am running in this error while running my program (though never opening /dev/null)

> couldn't open "/dev/null": Too many open files

I assume that I am leaking filehandlers at some point. But as I am not using raw `open` or `close` but `with-open-file` and `sb-ex:process-close` any process I create with `sb-ext:run-prgram` I am confused. As I do not know where I am leaking it would be pointless to post any code as it is too much to copy-paste and random samples wont help either.

**Therefore, how can I track filehandlers and isolate leaks?**

Comment: yes it does but not for lisp/sbcl though. It is a standard ubuntu 12.04 with Kernel 3.2.0-70-generic x86_64. As I am using ubuntu in combination with sbcl for some time now I assumed it was not OS related.

Comment: no use of the REPL (as I used buildapp to build an executable) and files are not kept open longer than a single function call - therefore I strictly use `with-open-file` to ensure that handlers are closed as soon as there aren't needed anymore. If it helps I could post the code handling lines/functions, though there would be quite a few lines and I did not want to overflow the question with code.

Comment: no I do not, will try that solution maybe it helps.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I tried your suggestion and the error does not occure anymore. Please feel free to post it as an answer for me to accept it.

Comment: did you get any more insight as to what exactly is happening?  I can post an answer if you'd like, but I don't have much more insight than "maybe buffered IO wasn't finished."  If you found any more specific details, you can post an answer yourself and accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be separate from your Lisp program, and rather a background issue on your system. Because you mention **/dev/null**, it sounds like you're on some flavor of Unix, and something like **lsof** might help in tracking down what's still open. The error messages aren't SBCL specific, so typical searched will only help you find general answers, though some of the investigation techniques may be relevant. Since you haven't posted any SBCL code, it's hard to provide any SBCL specific responses. (But maybe there are SBCL specific profiling tools. There could also be a disconnect between your calls letting file descriptors get closed, and SBCL actually closing them.

Now, even though it sounds like you're using the Common Lisp APIs correctly, there could be some surprising edge cases.  Are you sure you're not holding references to them anywhere that would keep them from getting released? A global list somewhere, or, doing things in the REPL where *****, ******, and ******* variables hold past results, could all contribute.

Now, another option is that the implementation might still have file descriptors open, even if the Common Lisp stream is closed.  **with-open-file** binds a stream for you, and that's an implementation's wrapper around the file descriptor. (I'd be surprised if SBCL is leaking like that, though.) For instance, if the output hasn't been flushed, it might be that the file descriptor stays around for a while. Using [**force-output** or **clear-output**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_finish.htm) might help with some of those issues.